# How to create custom field definitions with Sendgrid (v3) in C#?

Tags: c#, api, sendgrid, contacts

According to the V3 Sendgrid documentation, I can create custom definitions using their API:
https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/custom-fields/create-custom-field-definition

My code is as follows:

```
        public static async void addCustomDefinition(SendGridClient client)
        {
                var data = "{ 'name': 'test_name', 'field_type': 'Text' }";

                var response = await client.RequestAsync(
                    method: SendGridClient.Method.POST,
                    urlPath: "marketing/field_definitions", //"contactdb /custom_fields",
                    requestBody: data
                );

                Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
                Console.WriteLine(response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());

        }
```

However, I got the following output error message:

*BadRequest*
*{"errors":[{"field":"body","message":"invalid character '\'' looking for beginning of object key string"}]}*

What am I doing incorrectly?

**PS**: I changed the `urlPath` parameter:

...from online guide:
`urlPath: "v3/marketing/field_definitions,`

to this version:
`urlPath: "marketing/field_definitions",`

this newer version works for me on other commands such as getting field definitions and creating contact list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly stated, passing in the `urlPath` prefixed with `v3` doesn't work. This is because the `SendGridClient` will prepend it for you automatically. You can pass in the `version` named parameter to the constructor or use the `Version` property on `SendGridClient` to change the version that is prepended if needed.
It currently defaults to `"v3"`.

The other issue is that the `data` variable contains invalid JSON. In JSON single quotes are not allowed, and instead you have to use double quotes.
You can escape double quotes in a single-line string using a backslash:

```cs
var data = "{\"name\": \"custom_field_name\", \"field_type\": \"Text\"}";
```

You can escape double quotes in multi-line strings by adding extra double quote:

```cs
var data = @"{
    ""name"": ""custom_field_name"",
    ""field_type"": ""Text""
}";
```

Alternatively, you can create .NET objects and serialize them to a valid JSON string using [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to), [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), or other JSON libraries.

With these changes, your code should look like this:

```cs
public static async void addCustomDefinition(SendGridClient client)
{
    var data = "{ \"name\": \"test_name\", \"field_type\": \"Text\" }";

    var response = await client.RequestAsync(
        method: SendGridClient.Method.POST,
        urlPath: "marketing/field_definitions",
        requestBody: data
    );

    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());
}
```

It looks like the SendGrid client library has undergone some changes that aren't reflected yet in the document you linked. This issue and the other issues in the doc will be fixed soon.

Let us know if this fixed your problem!

Comment: The docs should now be fixed! 